# How to keep EOT in the end of string in php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to send a string to a server, which needs an EoT (control+D) in the end of the string. I am wondering how to concatenate the EoT to the end of a string?

Comment: ASCII 4 with [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)?... `'some string' . chr(4)`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Some funky stringy thingy" . "/r/n";
```

or

```
echo "Some funky stringy thingy" . chr(13) . chr(10);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: While this might answer the author's question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: What should that `/r/n` do? Shouldn't such special chars start with a backslash?

Comment: It depends on the context. When you say "send a string to a server", what exactly do you mean? Are you posting, ajax ect.    ?

Comment: @Jamie_D  No, I try to build a tcp connect.